# approximation with polynomials without stone weierstrass

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, approximation-theory

This is from a course in real analysis.
Let $f:G\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous bounded function and $G\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ an open bounded set.
Prove that for every compact set $K\subset G$ there is a series of polynomial that converge uniformly on $K$.

**I can't use Stone-Weierstrass theorem here**
. I can use the fact that polynomials are dense in $L_p$. Any ideas?

Comment: Your function $f$ is in $L^p$ (why?), so there is a sequence of polynomials, converging in $p$-norm to $f$. Maybe you can try to obtain the conditions for Egoroff's theorem? I don't have a solution, so take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: Can you use that result for $p = \infty$? Because when $p = \infty$, it is almost exactly what you are supposed to prove.

Comment: i can't use the result for $p=\infty$, but I might use egoroff ( we havn't proved it yet, but it is soon to be)